# How to remove the first and last character out of a 5 character String

Tags: java, arrays, char

I am creating a program in which you recieve a 5 character String from the user and not only do you turn it around, but you also remove both the first and last character of said String. I've gotten it to turn around, but I can figure out how to remove the characters, can anyone help please?

I tried multiple options, from using arrays, from other methods but nothing seems to delete them

Comment: If you have a string, and you need to discard the first and last character, just use [the `substring` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-)?

Comment: Or `StringBuilder#deleteCharAt`

Comment: `str = str.replaceAll(".(.)(.)(.).", "$3$2$1")`

Comment: _s = s.substring(1, 4)_.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuilder.substring method:

```
    String str = "Hello";
    str = new StringBuilder(str)
            .reverse()
            .substring(1, str.length() - 1);
    System.out.println(str);
```

check the str length before executing it to prevent from exceptions. The reason to use StringBuilder is because it makes string manipulation efficient - less copying and whats most important less memory allocations.

Comment: StringBuilder#subString returns a String, so no need to call toString

Answer (score 0):

String is immutable so you cant change it, but you can remove first and last characters by creating new String with:

```
String name = "Anna";
String newName = name.substring(1, name.length()-1));
```

Result is going to be: "nn"